# Symfony5 Doctrine Purger throws null Exception in integration test

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, phpunit, integration

I try to use the ORMPurger in an simple integration test with Symfony5 and ph8.1 but i get a null reference error on calling the purge function.

Has anybody an idea how to fix this? Or did i forgot something?

```
use App\Service\MyService;
use App\Entity\MyEntity;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class MyIntegrationTest extends KernelTestCase 
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        
        $purger = new ORMPurger();
        $purger->purge();
    }

    public function testSavingWithService(): void
    {
        $container = self::getContainer();

        /** @var MyService */
        $service = $container->get(MyService::class);

        $entity = (new MyEntity())
          ->setName('testing something');

        $success = $sevice->saveEntityToDatabase($entity);

        $this->assertTrue($success, 'should return true if entity is saved successfully');
    }
}
```

> Error : Call to a member function getMetadataFactory() on null

The Service itself works fine, i only want to purge the test database before every test run to be clear.

found the tutorial in symfony casts but that is old, based on symfony3.3 and symfony4, perhaps there is something to change for symfony5

Answer (score 0):

i found the error, forgot to give an EntityManagerInterface on creating ORMPurger

```php
public function setUp(): void
{
  self::bootKernel();
  
  /** @var EntityManagerInterface $manager*/
  $manager = self::getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
  $purger = new ORMPurger($manager);
  $purger->purge();
}
```